# How do you use your iPhone as a usb key?

Tags: iphone, data-transfer

I saw a friend of mine manage to use his iPhone as a usb key. I had a large file that I needed to transfer to his computer. So he gave me his iPhone cable, had me open iTunes, open his iPhone in iTunes, select some app that was on his iPhone, drag and drop my file there, and then he could get the file to his machine.

Which app was he using? I want it, too!

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it yet, but [from this description, it looks like Air Sharing is what I want.](https://superuser.com/questions/132293/how-to-use-itunes-usb-file-transfer-to-copy-files-from-pc-to-apple-ipad-e-g-pdf)

Comment: yes, like mummey had said, Air Sharing is exactly what you saw in action.

Answer (score 3):

Also try [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) which is useful even just on Macs no iOS devices. If file is put into a public share then you could see it on your PC as well not just his.

Comment: Dropbox wasn't what OP saw, but it IS FREAKIN GREAT. Everyone should use, everyone!

Comment: @Nathan G. - WTF? I **really** don't get why dropbox is anything worthy of comment. It's a web-file-sharing site. Big Whoop. My SVN server will kick it's ass.

Comment: Dropbox is not a web file sharing site. I replicates automatically an area of your file system to other machines. svn requies intervention. I put my repositories on dropbox for backup etc. (OK there is a web interface but not used)

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% relevant to the OP, but given the prices of flash memory these days and the hurdles one has to jump through to transfer arbitrary data to/from iOS devices I wouldn't recommend it.

If the user instead wants to access/modify the data while it's on the device the practice makes sense, but otherwise it is *much* more convenient today to just have a USB thumbdrive handy.

(BTW: The app in question was indeed likely to be Air Sharing, an app that's been available almost as long as the SDK has.)

Answer (score 0):

He has probably installed [USB Drive](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/iphone/use-your-iphone-as-a-usb-drive). It's a very simple application to convert your iphone as a USB key. I tried both on Windows and Mac and it works with ITunes. On windows you need to reboot to use the Drive Only Mode.